# Restrict particular app using internet

Tags: android, maps, android-maps-v2

I have an app displaying google maps v2. How to restrict the app to use internet to load tiles, and use local cache only, if internet connection is available on the device.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: There is no way to do so.

Comment: you can try https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/6291838?hl=en